# How to only download new files?

Tags: python, python-requests

So, i have this code that helps me to download all files in URL, but everyday there is a new file, how i can avoid downloading all the files in the url?

```
for link in soup.select("a[href$='v2.pdf']"):
    filename = os.path.join(folder_location,link['href'].split('/')[-1])
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(requests.get(urljoin(url,link['href'])).content)
```

Comment: Have you tried to check if `filename` exists before downloading it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this question [How do I list all files of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory) you can list all of the current files and directories using this code

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
mypath = './'
files = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
```

after you have gotten each of the file in a list you can then do a check for each file when downloading each of the files

```
for link in soup.select("a[href$='v2.pdf']"):
    filename = os.path.join(folder_location,link['href'].split('/')[-1])
    if (not filename in files):
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(requests.get(urljoin(url,link['href'])).content)
```

Comment: If it works, I am gonna research a bit. Have been using `if filename not in files` my entire life! :)

Comment: Either way works in this situation, Python is like that sometimes

Comment: i thought it was working but, it keeps downloading all the files everytime i run the script